# How to download complete source code of GPS and Google Maps

Tags: gps

I want to download complete source code of Gps and Google Maps.
First thing, using source code I want to understand how google maps store a new map(any society(residential area) which newly established, creates it's own map and add to google map). How Google map do this.
Second thing, how GPS works like when we turn on the directions in google maps it tell us for the next move.

I have tried much on google to find source code but didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Google keeps the source code of Google Maps closed-source. This means that it is not possible to read the source code of both the server and the client. It is possible to access the minified JavaScript on the client side, but this will not help you understand how Google Maps works. Try another service such as OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Does bing maps also an open source??

Comment: any useful link to understand if i am making an app how i would add new map in it??

Comment: I mean new created map not already present map like if I create an indoor map for a building then I want to add it in the app? How?